# Turkish special characters are not displayed correctly using utf8

Tags: php, utf-8, special-characters, htmlspecialchars

I have this page http://abone.doganburda.com/test/indexNew.php, when it was .html file there was no problem with Special Turkish character, everything was displayed correctly,

when I added some php code to it, and made it .php file, the special charcters showed this problem ,there is a part of the file is taken from external xml file is not displaying correctly,

I have added

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

and I have in the header the following but none of this solved the problem

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class=" js csstransitions" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
```

you can see this here

> Bu site, Do?an Burda Dergi Yay?nc?l?k ve Pazarlama A.?. taraf?ndan
>   T.C. yasalar?na uygun olarak yay?nlanmaktad?r. Sitenin isim ve yay?n
>   haklar? Do?an Burda Dergi Yay?nc?l?k ve Pazarlama A.?.?ye aittir.
>   Sitede yay?nlanan yaz?, foto?raf, harita, illüstrasyon ve konular?n
>   her hakk? sakl?d?r. ?zinsiz,kaynak gösterilerek dahi al?nt?
>   yap?lamaz.

it should be displayed correctly as here
http://abone.doganburda.com/test/

> Bu site, Doğan Burda Dergi Yayıncılık ve Pazarlama A.Ş. tarafından
>   T.C. yasalarına uygun olarak yayınlanmaktadır. Sitenin isim ve yayın
>   hakları Doğan Burda Dergi Yayıncılık ve Pazarlama A.Ş.’ye aittir.
>   Sitede yayınlanan yazı, fotoğraf, harita, illüstrasyon ve konuların
>   her hakkı saklıdır. İzinsiz,kaynak gösterilerek dahi alıntı
>   yapılamaz.

this is the response header for my php page

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date: Thu, 01 May 2014 13:19:53 GMT

Server: Apache/2.2.13 (FreeBSD) mod_ssl/2.2.13 OpenSSL/0.9.8e PHP/5.2.11 with Suhosin-Patch

X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.11

Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100

Connection: Keep-Alive

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Content-Language: tr
```

how can I display those special characterrs correctly

Comment: Did you **save** the file with UTF-8 encoding? Check your editor!

Comment: I have set notepad++ to utf8 encoding,
but it seems this is from a previous stage, I have solved this problem

Comment: I want to understand something, why it was .html everything was displayed correctly, then I added php code and the special character showed the problem

Comment: Are you saying that as a straight HTML file, the accented characters showed correctly (were edited and displayed as UTF-8), but when you added PHP code, they were corrupted? Or did the text itself go through an editing process (e.g., to put it into PHP _echo_ statements)? At some point, these characters appear to have been changed to some single-byte encoding, which is invalid in UTF-8.

Comment: “404 - File or directory not found.” when trying to access the page mentioned. This demonstrates why links to live pages are not sufficient in problem descriptions.

Comment: #Phil Perry 
I have removed the html page this is it will be referred to 404